# Exchange Server Name Ideas

Tags: exchange-2010

I am in the process of setting up a new Exchange Server but not sure on what to name it. Any suggestions? I am thinkng something like: EXSVR01, EX01, MailSVR01?

Comment: What should I buy my wife for her birthday?

Comment: Please read the help pages before posting again as you clearly chose to ignore the 'what this site if for and what it's not' information that appeared as you signed up.

Comment: Tlahuizcalpantecuhtli.  It's the Aztec god of dawn, which is poetic, and it'll also be easy for you to spell.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Pick a name that matches your current naming convention.